# c# How get form control name and parent project name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Sample:

```
Project Name: WpfApplication1
Form Name: MainWindow.xaml
```

How get do I get the runtime project name and form name?

Answer (score 0):

Mb this can help you:

```
var assemblyName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
//WpfApplication1.dll

var className = this.GetType().Name;
//MainWindow
```

Comment: Thx, i need form solution full path. Exp : project name : WpfApplication1 form info : New Folder\MainWindows.xaml

Answer (score 0):

If you want the project name use:

```
var projectName= Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
//WpfApplication1
```

In case the namespace of your MainWindow is WpfApplication1.NewFolder, You can retrieve it with:

```
var tmp = typeof (MainWindow).FullName;
//WpfApplication1.NewFolder.MainWindow
```

Note : you should edit your question because the second point is not very clear.